# Цикл не суммирует элементы массива, а reduce суммирует

Tags: javascript, html, массивы, for

Из input массив должен принимать элементы через запятую и суммировать их. Через метод reduce срабатывает, а через цикл for - нет. В чем проблема?

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function summaEltov() {
            let chisla = document.getElementById("znachenie").value.split(",");//.match(/\d{1,}/g);
            /*let resultat = chisla.reduce(function(sum, current) {
                return parseInt(sum) + parseInt(current);
            });*/
            function resultat () {
                var val = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < chisla.length; i++) {
                    return val += parseInt(chisla[i]);
                }
            };
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = resultat();
        };
    </script>
</head>

<body>
        <p>Введите значения через запятую:</p>
        <input type="text" id="znachenie">
        <button onclick="summaEltov()">Сложить</button>
        <p>Результат:</p>
        <div id="result"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: У вас не там `return` стоит.

Comment: Благодарю от всей души! Долго мучался. Через какие только методы не пускал, но через фор не работало. Спасибо! )))

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, обозначьте его как правильный.

Comment: Конечно. ))) Я этого уже минут 6 жду. Он сразу этого не дал сделал.

Comment: Готово! Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас `return` стоит внутри цикла, и получается что цикл выполняется один раз.

```js
function summaEltov() {
  let chisla = document.getElementById("znachenie").value.split(","); //.match(/\d{1,}/g);
  /*let resultat = chisla.reduce(function(sum, current) {
      return parseInt(sum) + parseInt(current);
  });*/
  function resultat() {
    var val = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < chisla.length; i++) {
      val += parseInt(chisla[i]);
    }
    return val;
  };
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = resultat();
};
```

```html
<p>Введите значения через запятую:</p>
<input type="text" id="znachenie">
<button onclick="summaEltov()">Сложить</button>
<p>Результат:</p>
<div id="result"></div>
```